# SQL Join is taking too much time

Tags: mysql, performance

I am using following SQL query

```
select count(*) from table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
ON table1.id = t2.orderId
WHERE table1.comunityId =149 AND table1.iscomunity = 0
AND (table1.job != 'Completed') AND (t2.status IS NULL OR t2.status != '1')
```

Its taking more then 1 min to load.
I have more then 70,000 rows in table1 and 6077 rows in table2.
Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "Please suggest me what I am doing wrong." - you're missing indexes. Generally speaking you should have an index for every foreign-key in your database.

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` comment in MySQL to see why a query is slow and to get ideas about what indexes you should add.

Comment: Thats is the documentation of der 'EXPLAIN' command: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html Pleas post the resualt of the explain statement.

Answer (score 2):

The comments under the answer already basically answer the question, short of suggesting actual indices, which I will do here:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 (comunityId, iscomunity, job);
-- add id to the end of the above index if not using InnoDB
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON table2 (orderId, status);
```

These indices target the join and where clause, and, if used, should speed up the count query.

Comment: Thanks for sharing me your answer, I made the changes in my database and seems to be its made the difference, it currently taking 39.2503 seconds now. Can that be reduce more if you compare 70,000 Rows in one table.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking me here.  The strategy I am suggesting above does not depend so much on the size of the tables, and in any case we don't have many options since you are doing a left join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen These are composite indexes - is that intentional? It looks like the OP is using single-column foreign-keys (not composite foreign keys), so composite indexes may not be as useful as separate indexes for each single column. Ideally we'd have to see the entire database schema first ofc. It does explain why their query execution time only dropped from 60s to 40s instead of sub-second (which suggests that MySQL is still doing a full table-scan somewhere).

Comment: @Dai Single column indices _might_ also work, but that would depend on things like cardinality of the data.  The indices I provided completely cover the entire query -- meaning, if used, the DB wouldn't even have to touch either of the two tables `:-)`

Comment: Dai and TimBiegeleisen, thanks for you suggestions, let me try to use indexes for each column and see if it making any difference.

Comment: Adding separate indices for each column may not do much here.  Keep in mind that most of the time MySQL will only use one index for each table in the query.  So, if single column indices seem to help, you should find out which one is being used.  In that case, the column of that index probably has very high cardinality.

Comment: @Dai - there is a significant performance improvement in having a composite key.  Most of the `WHERE` is compactly laid out in the index's BTree; this saves time.  And all the columns are in the index, so it is "covering".